# Irregular singular point & Frobenius form

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, frobenius-method

I have got the following differential equation.

$$z^3{\rm y}′′(z) + z\,{\rm y}′(z) + \lambda\,{\rm y} (z)=0$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant. 
I think I proved that at $z=0,$ the ODE has an irregular singular point. I always learned that you can't use Frobenius method now. But the question in the textbook says: By considering a solution of the Frobenius form:

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}$$

show that only one value of r is possible.

Can somebody please help me. Because I thought it was not possible. When I use the indicial equation, I can't get p(0) and q(0), so how do I have to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fall back to the raw form of the power series approach, insert the power series in the DE and compare coefficients,
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}a_n(n+r)(n+r-1)z^{n+r-2+3}+\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(n+r)z^{n+r-1+1}+λ\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^{n+r}=0
\\\iff\\
\sum_{n\ge1}a_{n-1}(n+r-1)(n+r-2)z^{n}+\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n(n+r)z^{n}+λ\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nz^{n}=0
\\\iff\\
a_0(r+λ)+\sum_{n\ge1}\Bigl[a_{n-1}(n+r-1)(n+r-2)+a_n(n+r+λ)\Bigr]z^{n}=0
$$

It could become a problem to prove that the resulting power series has a positive radius of convergence.

---

The constant term gives the indicial condition $r=-λ$, from the other coefficients one reads the recursion 
$$
a_{n+1}=-\frac{(n-λ)(n-λ-1)}{n+1}
$$
If $a_n=0$ at some index, then all the higher order coefficients are also zero and the solution is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ or less. If that is not the case, then 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|
=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,\frac{(1-\frac{λ}{n})(1-\frac{λ+1}{n})}{1+\frac{1}{n}}
=\infty
$$
giving no positive radius of convergence so that there is no solution via power series.

Comment: Thanks for giving this helpful hint. For the last line to be true, both coefficient has to be zero and a(0) cannot be equal to zero. So r = - lambda. And we get a recurrence relation for the second part in the brackets?

Comment: Yes. And you get $a_n$ growing like $n!$ preventing a positive radius of convergence. Except if $n-λ-1=0$ for some $n$, then the solution is a polynomial.

Comment: I don't get $a_n$ growing like n!. When I solve the recurrence relation It becomes all worse. For $a_1$ i finally get: $ {[-r (r-1)]/ (1+r +λ)}$ x $a_0 $. For $a_2$, it is getting worse. Do I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You already found that $r+λ=0$, which simplifies the fraction somewhat. And for larger $n$ the fraction $(n-λ-1)(n-λ-2)/n$ grows like $n$, considering the leading terms, so that the product of the fractions grows like, but is not exactly, $n!$.

Comment: Of course! To determine $a_1$, the denominator becomes "n". And λ vanishes. As a last question: when $λ=-1,0,1,2 ...$ can we say that the series solution terminates? And how can we show this?

Comment: I find your remark in the solution challenging. First of all: for the radius of convergence, we need to find a general solution. So we need $a_n$. After that it is a challenge to do the ratio test. To determine $a_n$, I already found that the denominator in fact is n!. But still puzzling on the numerator.

Comment: I still can't find a proper form for the numerator. I am struggeling with the following numerator: $(r+3)((r+2)^2((r+1)^2(r)^2(r-1)$, for $n=4$ in this case.

Comment: If you really want something resembling closed formulas use Gamma functons, something like $Γa_n=(-1)^n(n+r)Γ(n+r-1)/(n!\,Γ(r)Γ(r-1))a_0$. Maybe combine them to Beta expressions, $a_n=(-1)^nn!B(n+r,n)B(n+r-1,n)a_0$.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you have formulated. In general we can say that: $Γ(n+1)=nΓn=n!$. So in our case we have to "plug" in the values for $n+1$ and $n$. (The alternating form is clear $(-1)^n$).

Comment: This is true for general positive real $x$, $Γ(x+1)=xΓ(x)=x(x-1)Γ(x-1)$ etc. Which allows to write the falling products in a short notation. Another one is $x_{[k]}=x(x-1)...(x-k+1)$.

Comment: This is really interesting, although not part of the exercise, but certainly very exciting. What would happen if for instance $λ=1/2$?

Comment: I am puzzling, but I can't get to your solution in Gamma functions. Suppose my series is correct. Then I understand of course: $(-1)^n$ secondly, I can understand $Γ(n+r-1)$ in the numerator. Also the $n!$ in the denominator is 'logical'. But how do you get the $Γ(r)Γ(r-1)$ ?